# Why can differential privacy be proved using probability density function?

Tags: probability, cryptography

I am reading [The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf) and get confused about the proof of Therom 3.6 on page 36:

> **Theorem 3.6.** The Laplace mechanism preserves $(ε, 0)$-differential privacy.
> *Proof.* Let $x∈{\mathbb{N}}^{|\chi|}$ and $y∈{\mathbb{N}}^{|\chi|}$ be such that $||x − y||_1 ≤ 1$, and let $f(·)$ be some function $f : {\mathbb{N}}^{|\chi|} → {\mathbb{R}}^k$. Let $p_x$ denote the probability density function of $\mathcal{M}_L(x, f(·), ε)$ , and let $p_y$ denote the probability density function of $\mathcal{M}_L(y, f(·), ε)$. We compare the two at some arbitrary point $z ∈{\mathbb{R}}^k$
> $$\begin{split}
> \frac{p_x(z)}{p_y(z)}&={\prod}^k_{i=1}(\frac{exp(-\frac{\varepsilon|f(x)_i-z_i|}{\Delta f})}{exp(-\frac{\varepsilon|f(y)_i-z_i|}{\Delta f})})\\
> &={\prod}^k_{i=1}exp(\frac{\varepsilon(|f(y)_i-z_i|-|f(x)_i-z_i|)}{\Delta f})\\
> &\leq{\prod}^k_{i=1}exp(\frac{\varepsilon|f(x)_i-f(y)_i|}{\Delta f})\\
> &=exp(\frac{\varepsilon \cdot ||f(x)-f(y)||_1}{\Delta f})\\
> &\leq exp(\varepsilon)
> \end{split}$$

According to the definition of differential privacy given at **Definition 2.4**, we can use probabilities of an event to compute the privacy loss (e.g., **Claim 3.5**). So why did the authors use the probability density functions here, and why does it work..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shown that $\frac{p_x(z)}{p_y(z)} \leq \exp(\varepsilon)$ implies $\frac{Pr[A(x) \in S]}{Pr[A(y) \in S]} \leq \exp(\varepsilon)$ for all $S \subseteq range(A)$:

\begin{align}
Pr[A(x) \in S] &= \int_S p_x(z) dz \\
&\leq \int_S \exp(\varepsilon) \cdot p_y(z) dz \\
&= \exp(\varepsilon) \int_S p_y(z) dz \\
&= \exp(\varepsilon) \cdot Pr[A(y) \in S]
\end{align}

I assume the authors used the probability densities to simplify the proof since they do not need to deal with arbitrary sets $S$. I hope that explains all your questions!

Comment: A lof of thanks!!! (^v^)